Nondeterminism in Magma software while computing generators of an elliptic curve
Computing generators of a Mordell curve
$$y^2 = x^3 - 44275089430000,$$
can be done in Magma by running the following code:
SetClassGroupBounds("GRH");
Generators(EllipticCurve([0,-44275089430000]))

Multiple runs of this code in Magma calculator produces two different outcomes:
[]
false false

or
[ (18748450031360702684179393606032922472692419624480580773326199534256/3396838\
01416243388455124782355212643880890159427986479577965225 :
6967657247521859894337760812353908599119616220367281714549084326793359797075167\
8246596820708687007596/62605466439213150762495390467855187870102299492791336241\
99210595756050841608942926666398752875 : 1) ]
true true

The former result means that Magma failed to compute the rank (and generators) of the corresponding Mordell-Weil group, while the latter means it succeeded in that. The discrepancy in possible results seems to be explained by the random choices made during computations. The results can be deterministically reproduced by fixing the random seed as SetSeed(3); or SetSeed(0);, respectively.
So, the failure in computing generators for a given curve does not necessarily mean that Magma cannot do that, but may be just a result of particular "unlucky" random choices. This leads to practical questions:

Q: What are the chances of being just "unlucky" with computation of generators? What is the probability of remaining "unlucky" in a series of $n$ repeated computations (with different random seeds) of the generators for the same curve?


Random algorithms use a seed, which is just a long number. If you want a reproducible result, you can set the seed at the beginning of the code. If you don't, it still tells you what the seed was, so that you can reproduce the computation. No, that doesn't answer your question. I knew that.

@DaveBenson: I don't want reproducible failure here. Quite the opposite, I want randomness to help me in getting the generators computed. So, in the series of $n$ repeated computations I assume that the random seeds are all different from each other.

I was more thinking that once you get lucky you can jot down the seed so that you can reproduce your luck on demand.

@DaveBenson: This can surely be done, although my question not about reproducibility but about chances for success. Anyway, I have stated the possible seeds for both outcomes in the question.

The Magma calculator has a limit of 2 minutes. So the failure just means that Magma can not find the generators in that time.

You shouldn't run a random algorithm like this several times with the same arguments; instead you should tweak the optional arguments and finer methods. For instance MordellWeilRankBounds has an argument Effort that you can increase. Definitely you should use analytic methods, like Heegner points, for curves which end up having rank 1.

Actually @OlegEroshkin, I have the full version of Magma on my laptop. In a quick trial of 20 attempts, it failed 13 out of 20 times. So the question is valid for the full version as well.

@OlegEroshkin: It does not hit the time limit as it fails (when it fails) in much less than 120 seconds.

@ChrisWuthrich: Good point, but in this question I'd like to investigate the effect of randomness. I suspect that even with increased Effort computation may sometimes fail because of unlucky random choices.

I don't have access to magma to check what part of the algorithm is random. My guess is: It is rare for a curve to have this property that the algorithm is just at the boundary of succeeding sometimes, but not always. For each curve with this property, it will be difficult to figure out theoretically what the chances are, except of course by just testing 1000 times. Probably one should first study simpler arithmetic functions with random output related to class groups or number fields.
